# How do I run a C program several times and record the outputs?

Tags: c, batch-file

so basically I have a C program which does a lot of computation based on an input .txt file and outputs a value. I want to run it 100 times and then work out the average, obviously this would be tedious to do individually.

So I've tried to research a bit about scripting etc and I've found things like this:
https://answers.yahoo.com/question/?qid=20091206100348AAaJPP8
Am I supposed to just do this in my command prompt? (I'm on Windows btw)

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Unless you've installed `bash` (as part of cygwin or mingw or similar) you don't have it on Windows. You can write a batch script for similar purposes though. You should be able to find batch scripting tutorials to help you with this online.

Comment: I'm running c on mingw so do I just download bash?

Comment: Otherwise I have access to Linux computers at uni?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on Windows, so you can use a DOS batch script (.bat) to run your program N times using a loop (or N separate commands if that's easier for you).  Use the >> symbol at the end of the command to append the output to a file.  See http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true for more info on this, and search google for `dos bat file` for help on getting started with writing batch scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Have the program append the data into the text or csv file concerned and then write another program where you can run the program for a defined number of times. Use the function system(). It accepts a string as argument and executes it in the CUI.
Hope that helps.